# Import Apex application using cx_Oracle in Python

Tags: python, oracle, oracle-apex, cx-oracle

We would like to use our Python/cx_Oracle pipeline to import/install applications to Apex. So far, I have only found examples of doing this via SQL_PLUS.

I imagine that the Apex application export file is stored locally, as a file, and that Python loads it, whereafter cx_Oracle executes to the Apex database...

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: If you export an APEX application in the GUI you'll get a .sql file that includes both PL/SQL blocks and `SQL*Plus` commands.  I suppose you could write code in Python that would parse this file, discard the `SQL*Plus` commands, and execute each of the PL/SQL blocks in turn with `cx_oracle`.  That does not strike me as a particularly good use of anyone's time, though, and it seems like the sort of thing that is liable to break when the generated file contains a different `SQL*Plus` command.  I'd strongly suggest having Python make an OS call to launch `SQL*Plus` or `sqlcl` to run the file.

Comment: If you persist with the pure Python model, https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/8.1/samples/sample_env.py#L118-L151 has an example of basic execution but it does depend on having a simplified SQL file format e.g. using `/` for all statement termination and not `;`;.